# Why MongoDB is not saving the columns with null values which are not provided in create method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to insert some data in a collection and my schema looks like the below-mentioned code, But while performing create operation, I'm not able to see all columns in the DB at least with null values.

**CelebritySchema.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CelebritySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
born: {type: String, required: true},
height: {type: String, required: false},
connections: {
    father: {type: String, required: false},
    mother: {type: String, required: false},
    sister: {type: String, required: false},
    brother: {type: String, required: false},
    wife: {type: String, required: false},
    husband: {type: String, required: false},
    children: {
        son: {type: String, required: false},
        daughter: {type: String, required: false}
    }
},
profile: {
    name: {type: String, required: false},
    picture: {type: String, required: false},
    alt: {type: String, required: false},
    fullName: {type: String, required: false}
},
pictures: {
    sideBar: {
        image: {type: String, required: false},
        alt: {type: String, required: false}
    }
},
details: [
    {
        title: {type: String, required: false},
        data: {type: String, required: false}
    },

],
type: {type: String, required: false},
occupation: {type: String, required: false},
placeOfBirth: {type: String, required: false},
nationality: {type: String, required: false},
school: {type: String, required: false},
college: {type: String, required: false},
qualification: {type: String, required: false},
martialStatus: {type: String, required: false},
path: {type: String, required: false},
username: {type: String, required: false},
category: {type: String, required: false, default: 'celebrity'},
seo: {
    title: {type: String, required: false},
    description: {type: String, required: false}
},
socialMedia: {
    fb: {type: String, required: false},
    twitter: {type: String, required: false},
    insta: {type: String, required: false},
    linkedIn: {type: String, required: false}
},
honours: [{type: String, required: false}],
awards: [
    {type: String, required: false}
],
aboutMe: [{type: String, required: false}],
biography: [
    {
        title: {type: String, required: false},
        description: [
            {type: String, required: false}],
        image: {type: String, required: false}, alt: {type: String, required: false}
    },

],
latestNews: [{type: String, required: false}],
table: [{
    title: String,
    label: [String],
    data: [Object]
}]

}, {timestamps: true, toObject: {virtuals: true, getters: true}});

const Celebrity = mongoose.model('Celebrity', CelebritySchema, 'Celebrity');

 module.exports = Celebrity
```

I'm now trying to insert some data in the celebrity table using the code below.

```
Celebrity.create({
title:"title",
born:"today",
placeOfBirth:"USA"
}).then(r=> console.log(r))
```

Once it is saved in DB & When I try to check in DB, I have found only a few columns as shown in the below image

[image: Here in the picture it shows only a few columns]

Is there anything I'm missing in this code, why I'm not able to see all the columns in DB after saving the data?

Where all those columns are?
At least it should have been saved with null values.

Answer (score 3):

While having an analogy of a `collection` to a `table` and a `path`/`field` to a `column` helps in easy understanding if you're coming from a `SQL` background, it also creates confusion at times.

In a `SQL` table, for the columns you don't specify any value during insert, a default (null) value sets in. This is not true for mongodb documents which are nothing but binary `JSON`. In a `JSON`, unless you explicitly specify any field to be `null`, the field won't exist in your `JSON` object.

MongoDB is schemaless but mongoose is a wrapper which abstracts this and gives the impression of having a schema over mongodb documents. Now `mongoose`'s `Schema` is the place you can define validations/contraints/etc vanilla that usually comes with having a strict schema.

For insertion using `mongoose`'s `Model.create` method, you need to specify a `default` value against each `path/field` like this:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type: String, required: true},
  lastName: {type: String, required: true},
  fbImage: {type: String, required: false, default: ''},
  address: { type: Address, required: false, default: null }
});

const Address = new mongoose.Schema({
  street: {type: String, required: false},
  city: {type: String, required: false},
  country: {type: String, required: false}
});
```